# Trouble scraping website links in R using Rvest or Selenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape all the links or their css selector elements and put them into a list that can be ran through a loop that clicks on each link and runs code for each click. (I can't give the website link I am using.)

```
data_url <- website.php
links <- read_html(data_url) %>%
     html_elements("body") %>%
     html_attr("href")   # I get a 404 error. Is this failing bc it's a .php and not an .html?
#OR

linklist <- c()

links <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", value = '#maincontent > div.pad-helper > ul > li')

for (j in links) {
linklist <- append(linklist, j$getElementText()[[1]])
} #gets the text of the links, but not the href or the css selector. I tried findElements and that didn't work. (I don't have a full grasp of the RSelenium functions.)

df1trial <- as.data.frame(linklist) # I did a version where I got the css selector elements of all the links into the linklist, but it couldn't be converted to a dataframe

ilist <- df1trial$linklist

#start of loop
for (i in ilist){
Links <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", value = i)
Links$clickElement()
}
```

I have tried making a list of links, css selector elements, & just change the ccs elements' number in the loop, but don't know how to run a loop where the loop variable is in a string as seen below:

```
for (i in 1:10){
Links <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", value = "#maincontent > div.pad-helper > ul:nth-child(8) > li:nth-child(i) > a")# I believe this doesn't work bc the loop variable is in a string
Links$clickElement()
}
```

The other problem with this method is li:nth-child(i) number changes based on ul:nth-child(#)'s list length. It is a bunch of subheaders with different amounts of links listed underneath.